# The function doesn't give the output as expected

Tags: python, function, binary, hex

I defined a function by:
input : two numbers l,k
output: the number k in base l

Code:-

```
def base(k,l):
    result=''
    while k!=0:
        remainder = k%l
        k=k//l
        result= result + str(remainder)
    return result
```

The Problem occurs when the numbers are divisible by any power of the base.
For ex:- If base = 2 and k = 2, the output is 01 instead of 10. The same happens in some other numbers as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prepend the remainder:

```
result = str(remainder) + result
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not asking about efficiency, just how to get it to work.

A quick test using

```
def base(k,l):
    result=''
    while k!=0:
        remainder = k%l
        k=k//l
        result= str(remainder) +  result
    return result
```

works.